# Jenkins, cannot use multiple scm (git): cannot checkout, error 128

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I have 2 git repos: 
PyfaData
PyfaConn

If I try to run jenkins with just one of them, everything works fine.

Unfortunately PyfaData is dependent on PyfaConn so I need both.

I used source code management "git" and "multiple scms".

Only when I use two repos things start failing. Apparently "git" is not designed for that, so I use "multiple scms" and then add 2x git under that.

Regardless of the order I choose, the second repo that gets fetched returns `Checking out Revision 123abc.......` followed by `FATAL: Could not checkout 123abc....` and `reference is not a tree: 123abc....`

both repos have only the "master" branch

The complete error code is below (I tried to remove all sensitive info, please let me know if you notice I missed something :) )

Any ideas why this is failing?
Thanks!!

```
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress ...............git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2.................86523d (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2.................86523d
FATAL: Could not checkout 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2.................86523d
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2.................86523d" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: reference is not a tree: 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2.................86523d



at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$900(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2341)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ......................
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:389)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor631.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1242)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM.checkout(MultiSCM.java:143)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
        at hudson.matrix.MatrixRun.run(MatrixRun.java:153)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2.................86523d
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2365)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked other similar questions, but in all other questions I found users have this error 128 regardless of the configuration, I only get this on the second git repo I add to my jenkins job.

--- update:
I am creating this job by using the Multi-configuration Project

--- update2:

The problem -after long looking at it- looks a lot like a bug: it happens in the Multi-configuration Project, and while the parent console output shows correctly 2 different s (for example 421ed02c45a6ac0ffd2........ and 0987dc9087f687........)  for each of the 2 repos, each of the children spanned from the configuration matrix shows the same revision number for both repos, and it fails to checkout the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related with Jenkins Bug

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23445

apparently the solution is not to use the multiconfiguration project plugin, but try to get away with a pipeline instead.

This is a lot more tedious and requires groovy scripting, so not really a solution, but definitely an answer to my question.